# return and assign global value from macro function in data setp

Tags: sas

Not quite sure the best way to do the following - I want to call a macro function from within a DATA step, passing as an argument the value from an existing column, and assign the value generated by the macro function to a new column. I'm open to any approach - PROC SQL, CALL EXECUTE, etc.

```
%macro simple(x=);
    %global value;
    %let value = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), &x, same)); 
    %put &value;
%mend simple;
%simple(x=1);

data have;
    do x = 1 to 15;
        output;
    end;
run;

data want;
    data have;
        newdate = %simple(x);
run;
```

Comment: Can you use PROC FCMP instead? DOSUBL may return in same session, but CALL EXECUTE is after the data step ends, so won't do what you want.

Comment: Hi again! If you can provide an example that would help - I will also look into PROC FCMP in the meantime

Comment: Is your example above representative? Is that function actually what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's simpler for sure but I think it captures my problem. I can try to update my post if the solution seems to not address my real world case.

Comment: Don't use `data` where you mean `set`.  Probably useful to add a format to your new variable so that it prints the dates in a human readable format.

Comment: Ok that was silly of me - Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the changes to %SIMPLE and where it is called.  RESOLVE works for this case but
%COMPLEX :-) will not.  Also this is better done without calling a macro it can all be done in data step.  I hope you have a better use for this than job security.

```
%macro simple(x=);
   %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), &x, same))
   %mend simple;

%put NOTE: %simple(x=1);

data have;
    do x = 1 to 15;
        output;
    end;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   newdate = input(resolve(cats('%simple(x=',x,')')),F16.);
   format newdate date9.;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: Do you mind *also* showing how this could be done in DATA step? I can't seem to make that work either - I can show what I tried in my post if necessary.

Comment: `input(resolve(…))` is a coding pattern I wasn't aware of - I'm sure I'll abuse it needlessly

Comment: To call `intnx()` in a data step instead of in macro code just don't wrap it in `%sysfunc()`.

Comment: Hi @Tom - I've edited my post with sample code (at bottom) - it's not giving me output I expect...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the macro in the middle of a statement like:

```
newdate = %simple(x);
```

then the macro can only emit part of a statement. That is no semi-colons.

In this case if you define the macro to generate the call to INTNX() then you could use it that way in an assignment statement.

```
%macro simple(value);
  intnx('month',%sysfunc(today()),&value,'same')
%mend simple;
```

So if today() is 20NOV2018 then you are effectively running this valid SAS statement in your data step.

```
newdate = intnx('month',21508,x,'same') ;
```

Notice how the **name** of the variable X is what is passed to macro and what is used in the generated piece of SAS code.

Of course your macro is now useless if you wanted to try to use it outside of a SAS statement.

Comment: That's cool! In real life, I'm using a multi line macro function so having both options is great